# Android-Gradle error "more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using GCM and set almost same as the sample project of Google. That build.gradle is mine below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}
```

And another build.gradle is below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.min.photozzle"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

// Testing dependencies
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'


compile group: 'com.kakao.sdk', name: 'kakaolink', version: '1.1.0'
compile group: 'com.kakao.sdk', name: 'kakaostory', version: '1.1.0'// 카카오스토리 sdk를 사용하기 위해 필요.
compile group: 'com.kakao.sdk', name: 'kakaotalk', version: '1.1.0'    // 카카오톡 sdk를 사용하기 위해 필요.
compile group: 'com.kakao.sdk', name: 'push', version: '1.1.0'    // push sdk를 사용하기 위해 필요.

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
}
```

Without some points needed to customize our app, the sample project of Gcm provided by Google and my project's build.gradle are almost same. But sample project works well but my project says:

> 'Error: more than one library with package name
>   'com.google.android.gms'

Comment: @MD Thank you for asking that question, but as I know by coding build.gradle, importing google_play_services.jar is not necessary isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

in `project-level build.gradle`

and add

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
```

in `app-level build.gradle`

Check the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) what it said

Answer (score 0):

com.kakao.sdk:push:1.1.0 has a dependency on com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87 which conflicts with your declared dependency of com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0

You can use gradlew app:dependencies to check the dependency tree of your build.gradle file.